# How to handle multiple versions of an application?

Tags: version, production

I've build an iOS and Android app with a nodejs backend server that is now in production, but as I'm new to this I have no idea on how to handle update of server and apps.

First of all, how am I supposed to update the nodejs server without downtimes?

Second, let's suppose I have a chat on my app and for some reasons I have to change it but the change is not compatible with the previous versions, how am I supposed to act?

I think the question is not entirely clear, but I have no idea on what to search on google to point me in the right direction, anything would be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. updating your backend server is a pain indeed. you can't really do that without downtime at all. what you can do though, assuming your clients access your server with a domain rather than with a plain IP address, is prepare another server with an as-up-to-date data as possible and do a DNS record update to redirect the data to it. keep in mind that DNS has a long update time in which some clients get to the old server and some to the new one (which means a big headache if data consistency is important to you)
2. changing the API is another pain. often times you need to support older versions of your application in parallel to the newer ones. most app stores will let you know the statistics of your app versions and when it's safe to drop support for an old version.
   a common practice though is you have the API endpoints versioned so that version 1 of you app accesses `URL/API/v1/...` and version to accesses `URL/API/v2/...` which enables you sending different replies based on your client version. you increase the version every since you make a breaking change to the protocol. this makes a "future compatible" protocol
3. at some cases you initially add a mechanism that lets the server send a message to an old version of the client saying that their version is obsolete and they need to update...

most big apps already has such mechanism while most small apps just take the risk of some downtime and drop support for a few non-updated clients...

Answer (score 2):

**Updating server without downtime**

The answer really depends upon how your infrastructure is configured.

One way would be to have a second server, configured with the new software, ready to go, and then you switch over to the new server. If you are going to be doing this a lot, then having a mechanism/tooling to do this will certainly simplify things. If things also go wildly wrong, you just switch back.

We use AWS. As part of launching an update, we provision a number of instances to match the current number (so we don't suddenly need several hundred more instances launching). When all the instances are ready to go, our load balancer switches from the current configuration to the new configuration. No one sees anything other than a slight delay as the caches start getting populated.

**Handling incompatible data**

This is where versioning comes in.

Versioning the API - The API to our application has several versions. Each of them is just a proxy to the latest form. So, when we upgrade the API to a new version, we update the mappers for the supported versions so that the input/output for the client doesn't change, but internally, the main library of code is operating only on the latest code. The mappers massage data between the user and the main libraries.

Versioning the data being messaged - As this is an app, the data coming in should be versioned, so app sending v1 data (or unversioned if you've not got a version in there already) has to be upgraded on the server to the v2 format. From then on, it is v2. On the way out, the v2 result needs to be mapped down to v1. It is important to understand that the mapping may not always be possible. If you've consolidated/split attributes from v1 to v2, you're going to have to work out how the data should look from the v1 and v2 perspectives.

Versioning the data being stored - Different techniques exist depending upon how the data is being stored. If you are using an RDBMS, then migrations and repeatables are very commonly used to upgrade data ready for a new app to operate on it. Things get interesting when you need to upgrade the software to temporarily support both patterns. If not using an RDBMS, a technique I've seen is to upgrade the data on read. So, say you have some sort of document store, when you read the document, check the version. If old, upgrade and save it. Now you can treat it as the latest version. The big advantage here is that there is no long running data migration taking place. Over time, the data is upgraded. A downside is that every read needs to do a version check. So. Maybe mix and match. Introduce the check/upgrade/save happen on every read. Create a data migration tool whose sole job is to trawl through the data. When all the data is migrated, drop the checks (as all the data is either new and therefor matches the latest version or has been migrated to the latest version) and the migrator.

I work in the PHP world and I use Phinx to handle DML (data) migrations and our own repeatables code to handle DDL (schema changes).

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for this for a long time. Do know know a where to find full detail articles about this?

Comment: Most of this is just stuff I've picked up over the last 30 years as an application developer. The idea at its core is to do SMALL upgrades. Takes longer, but allows you to rollback to a working system when things don't work out right. But that itself is just 1 approach. Others may say publish and fix on fail. If you've got the team for that then fine. Just remember that the entire team needs to agree the strategy being used otherwise the random failures that can happen will bite you and then the bosses get involved wanting to know why they are getting customer complaints.